# Using OAUTH to post to a twitter users wall

Tags: php, twitter

would it be possible to post to different users walls authenticating with OAUTH?

Basically what I would like to do is authenticate a user, and then post something to their wall, this is all with the users knowledge of course, so the user would be greeted with a login screen, they log in, and something gets posted to their twitter wall using a PHP sdk.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!, you can find more info in this [article](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the basic low-level REST API [statuses/update](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update) method, which your PHP SDK would invoke, Twitter also offers [@anywhere](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere), a Javascript API that let's you pretty quickly integrate with the service.  The [TweetBox](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin#tweetbox) is the widget that would allow your users to post status updates from your site.